# What are conditions on existence of local orthogonal coordinate system on two-dimensional Lorenzian manifold?

Tags: surfaces, orthogonality, semi-riemannian-geometry

Consider two-dimensional Lorenzian manifold i.e. of signature $(1,1)$. Does there always exist on every point local coordinate chart so that the corresponding coordinate one-forms are orthogonal i.e. $g(dx,dy) = 0$?

If there exists surfaces for which this is not possible, is there some good condition on their metric for classification?